# getting an error didn't return an HttpResponse object. What is going on?

Tags: python, django

For the first time i am trying to create a small django application. It is just a basic page with two forms, a search form, which returns values from a database (working well), and a insert form (the problem). In the insert form there are three text fields asking for values for a new row in the database. The app is called "searcher". Here is my code:

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
from searcher.models import Publisher
from django.db.models import Q

def search(request):
    if "search" in request.GET:
        value = request.GET['search']
        results = Publisher.objects.filter(Q(city__contains=value) | Q(name__contains=value))

    else:
        value = "No term"
        results = []
    template = get_template("base.html")
    html = template.render(Context({"value":value, "results":results}))
    return HttpResponse(html)

def insert(request):
    if "name" in request.POST:
        for key in request.POST:
            counter = 0
            if key != '':
                counter = counter + 1
        if counter == len(request.POST):
            row = Publisher(name=request.POST['name'], city=request.POST['city'], website=request.POST['website'])
            row.save()
```

base.html

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form method = "GET" action = "">
            <input type  = "text" name = "search"><input type = "submit">
        </form><br>

        you searched for:{{value}}<br>

        your results:
        {% for result in results %}
            <br>{{result}}<br>
        {% endfor %}    
        <br><br>
        <form method = "POST" action = "/test/insert/">
            <input type  = "text" name = "name" value = "name"><br>
            <input type  = "text" name = "city" value = "city"><br>
            <input type  = "text" name = "website" value = "website"><br>
            <input type = "submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from searcher import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^test/$', views.search),
    url(r'^test/insert/$', views.insert),
)
```

the error is saying "ValueError at /test/insert The view searcher.views.insert didn't return an HttpResponse object." as a result of me submitting the insert form.

I understand what the error is saying: sorry but all views in views.py MUST return something to show.

Firstly why is this?

And secondly what is the correct way to accomplish the insert form ? Currently i have set the form action = "/test/insert/" so that in urls.py it can recognise the insert form was submitted and call the function insert, how should the function be called instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be asking two questions

1. "Why must all views return something to show?"

   You're misinterpreting the error message. The error you saw didn't
   say "all views MUST return something to show" - it only said
   "searcher.views.insert didn't return an expected HttpResponse".
   Since you're dealing with a HTTP request (a form POST), you're
   expected to send back a HTTP Response. All HTTP requests expect a
   response - this is a matter of a standard agreement on how to
   communicate - the details are part of the [http standard
   definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), and somewhat explained as part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473038/post-versus-ajax-call).
2. "What is the correct way to accomplish the insert form?"

   You're implementing it correctly - just send back a HTTP Response
   for the POST. The code for it is almost identical to what you're
   sending back in response to the Search request (maybe you'll want to
   add a message in saying that the insert completed successfully,
   where in the Search request you might have returned the item that
   was being searched for?).

   If you'd like to avoid having to refresh the form altogether, you might want to use an ajax call, instead of a http call, again, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473038/post-versus-ajax-call).

Comment: The thing is is that I was hoping this insert function could be considered completely server side, so it is like: "On a trigger, do this server side function". For now I was wanting to see how to run the function using the method i am using, but alter it a little to prevent the error? Surely there is a way of running a function without having to return an HttpResponse each time, that is a nightmare (I come from the world of PHP)!  Is views.py definitely the right place to put a function like this? I mean, its a file full of functions that return things to SEE.

Comment: Maybe you want to do something other than a Post via HTTP - use javascript to do an Ajax call (a Post via XmlHttpRequest) - see the second link in my answer

Comment: Sorry to be annoying, but what if i did not want it to be AJAX? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: there are lots of different ways to communicate with the server - you can try something even more complicated, like using websockets. There's no real point in going that way for your example, though.

Answer (score 1):

All views must return an `HttpResponse` object because that's what the server returns to the browser that initially makes the request.  Pretty much by definition, a view is a callable that accepts a request object and returns a response object.

It's fine to have code in views.py that doesn't return a response, such as helper functions for a view, but it's not fine to use such code as a view.

The usual pattern when working with POST requests is to return a redirect to a success page, on success, and to redisplay the form with the appropriate error messages on failure.  See for instance the ["Using a form in a view"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view) docs.

Comment: Ok, so the only way to fix this is to return a success message (or anything like that)? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: You have to return something.  If the form was submitted by a human on a web page, the usual practice is to return a redirect to a page with a success message when it succeeds - you want to get the user off the page with the form to avoid accidental multiple submissions.  The absolute bare minimum you could return on success is HTTP status 204, "No Content", but you wouldn't use that under normal circumstances.