# HTTP Post and redirect

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, http, redirect

I have the following controller action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post | HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var postedData = Request.Form["param1"];
    return View("/someView.cshtml");
}
```

When I post data to it in the following way:

```
$('#btn1').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: someUrl,
        data: { param1: 'some data' },
        async: false //tried without this line with no affect
    });
});
```

It doesn't redirect and it requires a registration to the success callback and invocation of a `window.location.href` to redirect to the view.
If I'll create a form and submit it with the data to the same controller action a redirection will occur in the same request.

Why does a jquery  post doesn't trigger a redirection whereas a form submit to the same action does? Do I have to use a form in order to `POST` and redirect over the same request?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473038/post-versus-ajax-call

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538523/how-to-get-an-asp-net-mvc-ajax-response-to-redirect-to-new-page-instead-of-inser

Comment: Ajax response is handled within the Ajax request and no redirects are happening, unless you have a location change script in the response from Ajax call

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the same page (ajax calls never redirect). If you want to redirect, make a normal submit.